# JSON parse class java

Tags: android

Estou tendo algumas duvidas, como faço para fazer um parse de um JSON que está vindo do webservice.

Minha classe `comentarios` está assim:

```
public class Comentarios extends BaseEntity {

 private Integer avaliacao;
 private String observacaoAvaliacao;
 private String nmCliente;

 public Comentarios(Integer avaliacao, String observacaoAvaliacao, String nmCliente) {
    avaliacao = avaliacao;
    observacaoAvaliacao = observacaoAvaliacao;
    nmCliente = nmCliente;
 }

 public void setAvaliacao(Integer avaliacao) {
    this.avaliacao = avaliacao;
 }

 public void setObservacaoAvaliacao(String observacaoAvaliacao) {
    this.observacaoAvaliacao = observacaoAvaliacao;
 }

 public void setNmCliente(String nmCliente) {
    this.nmCliente = nmCliente;
 }

 public Integer getAvaliacao() {
    return avaliacao;
 }

 public String getObservacaoAvaliacao() {
    return observacaoAvaliacao;
 }

 public String getNmCliente() {
    return nmCliente;
 }
}
```

Meu JSON está vindo do servidor assim:

```
Resposta: {
  "sucesso": true,
  "mensagem": " Comentarios listados com sucesso. ",
  “comentarios”:[
     {
       “avaliacao”:”4”,
       “observacaoAvaliacao”:”Restaurante muito bom, valeu a pena comer o crepe de frango, e muito melhor é o aplicativo.”,
      “nmCliente”:”Renan R.”
     }
  ]
 }
```

Preciso acessar assim:

```
Comentarios comentarios;
comentarios.getNmCliente();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente sua pergunta é só atribuir os valores ao objeto comentario e depois retirar o nome com este metodo, pode ser assim...

```
Comentario comentario = new Comentario();
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(resposta);
JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(0); // caso vc só tenha um objeto... caso não vc faz um for... populando uma ArrayList<Comentario>
comentario.setAvaliacao(jsonObj.getInt("avaliacao"));
comentario.setObservacaoAvaliacao(jsonObj.getString("observacaoAvaliacao"));
comentario.setNmCliente(jsonObj.getString("nmCliente"));
```

agora vc pode retirar item por item usando os get's da sua classe Comentario no objeto comentario que foi criado... lembrando que se você tiver mais de um objeto no retorno do JSON do webserver vc deve usar uma ArrayList e popular ela com o for..

```
   // Exemplo com for:

    ArrayList<Comentario> listaComentarios = new ArrayList<Comentario>; // cria a lista de comentarios

    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(resposta);

    for(int i = 0; i < json.lenght; i++){
        Comentario comentario = new Comentario();
        JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(i); // pega o objeto de indice i
        comentario.setAvaliacao(jsonObj.getInt("avaliacao"));
        comentario.setObservacaoAvaliacao(jsonObj.getString("observacaoAvaliacao"));
        comentario.setNmCliente(jsonObj.getString("nmCliente"));
        listaComentarios.add(comentario); // adiciona o comentario de indice i a lista de comentarios 
    }
```

Comment: São muitos comentarios, tem como fazer o exemplo para um array de objetos ?

Comment: Para converter JSON para um objeto Java (POJO) eu sugiro a biblioteca Gson do Google.

Comment: @Piovezan gostaria de acrescentar uma resposta com sua dica, acho que a valida, mesmo que eu ja tenha aceitado a anterior, devido a novas tecnologias

Comment: @RenanRodrigues É só acrescentar, você pode mudar a resposta aceita depois de já ter aceitado.

Comment: Vale a pena então você indicar algo melhor, tem como ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues Não entendi sua pergunta. Eu já indiquei algo melhor, que é a biblioteca Gson do Google.